# Error being shown after trying to execute jar file on terminal

Tags: java, terminal, jar

The .jar file that I have created doesn't seem to be running when I am trying to execute it through the terminal

I selected Jar to be a `Runnable JAR FILE export` The file name is titled grades.jar, it's a suppose to execute a GUI application that I've created. Also the `Launch configuration:` that I've selected contains the main

```
   package GUI.project;

   public class GradeAnalyzer extends Application {
   private HBox hBox;
   private Button yesButton,noButton;
   private BorderPane bp, bp2;
   ScoreList scoreList = new ScoreList(100);
   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

      GradeError_window error = new GradeError_window();
      GUImain screen = new GUImain();

      hBox = new HBox();
      hBox.setTranslateX(40);
      hBox.setTranslateY(10);

      bp  = new BorderPane();
      bp2 = new BorderPane();

      yesButton = new Button("yes");
      noButton = new Button("no");

      yesButton.setMinWidth(50); //set width of the buttons
      noButton.setMinWidth(50);
      noButton.setTranslateX(20);

      yesButton.setOnAction((e)->
      {
            FileChooser chooseFile = new FileChooser();

           chooseFile.setTitle("Slecet .txt file");
           FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");

        chooseFile.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
        File file = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(stage);

        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            while(scan.hasNext() && scan.hasNextDouble())
            {
                scoreList.add(Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine()));
            }

            if(scoreList.getList().isEmpty()) { //This will open a new window if the file selected doesn't contain numbers
                try {
                    error.start(stage);

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }
            else {
                screen.start(stage, scoreList.getList(), scoreList);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    });

    noButton.setOnAction(e->{
        screen.start(stage, scoreList.getList(), scoreList);
    });

    Label label = new Label("Would you like to load a file?");

    hBox.getChildren().addAll(yesButton,noButton);

    bp2.setCenter(label);
    bp.setTop(bp2);
    bp.setCenter(hBox);

    stage.setTitle("Grade Analyser");
    Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setWidth(200);
    stage.setHeight(90);
    stage.show();

    stage.setMinWidth(stage.getWidth());
    stage.setMinHeight(stage.getHeight());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
```

}

I expect for the program to be running the terminal, but its saying

> Error: Could not find or load main class GUI.project.GradeAnalyzer

Comment: How are you building your jar?

Comment: I write click on my project, select export, go to the java folder and select "Runnable Jar file", after I select GradeAnalyzer because it contains my main, and save it to my desktop, then use java -jar grades.jar to run the file, but then it says cant fine or load main

Comment: are you running in from a command prompt that has a current directory being that of your Desktop?

Comment: The jar file is located in my desktop, so I am using the terminal to view all the files in the desktop by using 'cd' and the 'ls' to view my files. I then execute it by using java -jar grades.jar

Comment: You should ***start*** by examining the contents of your jar file. It is a zip. You can open it with any zip file archiver (or use `jar tvvf grades.jar`). My **guess** is that you have exported the source rather than the compiled class files. But without more information, it is hard to say.

Comment: I have entered jar tvvf grades.jar and viewed all the classes i think

Comment: 5317 Mon Jul 08 17:13:18 MST 2019 GUI/project/GradeAnalyzer.class